# i am trying to use ajax in form submitting but it is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, eclipse, jsp

I am using ajax to submitting my form but ajax is not including in my code i dont know why.

this is my form and how i am using my ajax

```
<div class="login-box">
        <h2>Sign up</h2>
        <form id="reg-form" action="RegisterServlet" method="POST">
            <div class="user-box">
                <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name"> <label>User
                    Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="user-box">
                <input type="email" id="user_email" name="user_email"> <label>Email
                    address</label>
            </div>
            <div class="user-box">
                <input type="password" id="user_password" name="user_password">
                <label>Password</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="gender">Gender</label> <br> <input type="radio"
                    id="gender" name="gender" value="male">Male <br> <input
                    type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female">Female
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" name="check" class="form-check-input"
                    id="check"> <label class="form-check-label"
                    for="exampleCheck1">Terms & Conditions</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn primary-background text-black">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

and this is how i am using ajax

```
<!-- Java Script -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script
        src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/myjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          console.log("Loaded");
          
          $('#reg-form').on('submit',function(event){
              console.log("Inside reg form");
              
              event.preventDefault();
              let form=new FormData(this);
              
              $.ajax({
                  console.log("Inside ajax");
                  url: "RegisterServlet",
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: form,
                  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                      console.log(data);
                      
                      
                  },
                  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                      
                      console.log(jqXHR);
                      
                      
                      
                  },
                  processData: false,
                  contentType: falses
                  
                  
              });
              
              
              
              
              
          });
          
      });
      
      </script>
```

i have also included script file for ajax if i have to include another script file then please tell what it is and please help me solve this error.

Comment: So you have somenthing like `falses is not defined` in console?

Comment: My console is not showing anything its directly redirecting to register servlet page

Comment: mmm... You have to make sure that script gets loaded before even think debugging it. Clear browser cache maybe? I can't tell more.

Comment: null
Served at: /Computer_Course i am getting this error in console

Comment: Does that error show in your browser console tab ? Please elaborate .